# MySql query exception

Tags: java, mysql

When i am trying to insert values in MySQL table through java code, I am getting the exception:

> com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`icd_app_suite/mapper`, CONSTRAINT `FK_mapper_1` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `user_detail` (`user_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE)

What can be the cause?

Answer (score 3):

The error is clear: you're inserting (or updating) a row which doesn't respect a foreign key in referenced table.
So you first have to insert *father* record, then *child* record.
Probably you're adding a record on **user_detail** table with **ID** field not present in **user** table

Answer (score 0):

You are inserting a row with a value in the `user_id` column that is not found in the `user_id` column of the `user_detail` table